# How to look inside <app-root> element by jmeter?

Tags: angular, jmeter

i need to see some element inside  ex.  or  by j-meter , but program cant see it in View Results tree.

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="test.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Angular application is a kind of JS application that creates its content on client side (Browser) on the fly. Generated content is than injected into `<app-root>`. You cannot get its content using static web scraping methods like you probably try to use.

What you need is either real browser or its equivalent that supports JS, open given page, wait for application to generate and then investigate DOM using standard techniques.

You can try to use Selenium for that - it is framework that allows you to control the browser - thus do what I have described above. I have used selenium with headless chrome browser for web scraping in the pass with a great success.

Details on exactly how to do this I too broad do describe and off topic on this question.

Answer (score 0):

As per JMeter project main page:

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So my expectation is that your `<app-root>` tag content is being populated via some form of an [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) request which is being triggered by JavaScript when you open the page using a real browser but it's not automatically executed when you run a JMeter test. You can reproduce the behavior in the browser by [disabling JavaScript](https://www.wikihow.com/Disable-JavaScript)

So you need to add an extra [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler in order to mimic this AJAX call and the `<app-root>` tag content will be returned as the response.

If there is more than one AJAX request triggered by the main page of your application you should put corresponding HTTP Request samplers under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) as real browsers execute AJAX requests in parallel and well-behaved JMeter test must represent this network footprint with 100% accuracy